# iOS SwiftLocation library: How to get placemark from location?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, location

I'm using this library to get location: 
https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftLocation

Before I was using version 2 of the library, and getting the placemark was as simple as this:

```
Location.getPlacemark(forLocation: location, success: { (placemark) -> Void in
    guard let receivedPlacemark = placemark.first else {
        return
    }
    logger.debug("Retrieved placemark: \(receivedPlacemark.locality ?? "-")")
    self.currentPlacemark = receivedPlacemark
}, failure: { (error) -> Void in
    logger.error(error)
})
```

The problem is that now I can't find a getPlacemark method in the new version of the library (they are on version 3). Searching in his readme  I can't find a function to get the placemark.

This is the way you can get a location now with the version 3 of the library:

```
Locator.currentPosition(accuracy: .neighborhood, onSuccess: { location in
    self.currentLocation = location                              
}) { (err, lastLoc) in
    logger.error(err)
}
```

Any help with this issue will be very grateful

Comment: Did you look at least that part of the ReadMe: https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftLocation#reverse-geocoding-from-address-to-location--from-coordinates-to-place ?

Comment: yes @Larme and i look the line with this " If you are using Apple services you can get placemark to retrive the associated CLPlacemark instance." but I don't understand how to get it! they are not explaining it. And there is not a function to get it like in the version 2. If you understand how to get it from a location please can you post an answer with the sample? thank you

Comment: `Locator.location(fromCoordinates: coordinates, using: .apple, onSuccess: { places in print(places)}) { err in print(err)}`. I guess that `guard let receivedPlacemark = placemark.first else` will be `guard let receivedPlacemark = places.first else`. And `location` might be `coordinates` param, it's just a CLCoordinate2D param I think, if it's not location, it might be on of its properties. I didn't download the lib, and it's hard navigate between classes (no link to get definition)...

Comment: @Larme thank you but I can't make that working to get the placemark from a location

Comment: @Larme it gives an array of places, and I want only the placemark of a given location

Comment: Get the first one as you did before?

Comment: Thank you @Larme I just was trying that one minute ago, and now I'm getting this error: Cannot assign value of type 'Place' to type 'CLPlacemark?' It seems that places array is from type Place and i need a CLPLacemark

Comment: I don't know what is a `Place` object. As I said, it's hard to get definition (not like in XCode) of it in GitHub navigation. But this tell more about it: https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftLocation#from-address-string-to-location So I guess it has a property `placemark`?

Comment: thank you so much @Larme! it seems its the way! now I'm trying to test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was from @Larme in the comments to get the Placemark:

```
Locator.location(fromCoordinates: location.coordinate, using: nil, onSuccess: { places in
    guard let receivedPlacemark = places.first?.placemark else {
        return
    }
    self.currentPlacemark = receivedPlacemark    
}) { err in
    logger.error(err)
}
```